# SQL Server constraint. Maximum number of rows filtered by field

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

First of all sorry for my English.

My problem: I have an application using Asp.Net + EF code-first. I have one table in SQL Server:

```
Id   TypeId   Name
--------------------
1    1        Suite
2    1        Desk
```

In my app there two inserts that are running in 2 threads.

I need to create a constraint on my table - there can be only 3 rows per table for `TypeId = 1`.

So if two threads make a query, only one can be successful, because 1 rows left for TypeId = 1.

How can I check this?How can I run insert not concurrently or maybe you have other great solutions?

Constraint of rows count for each TypeId can be different. There are another table called TypeConstraints where stored two columns.

```
TypeId  RowsCount
1       3
2       5
3       4
4       11
5       8
```

and so on..

HAVE FOUND SOLUTION:

```
ALTER function dbo.UdfCheckCount (
        @TypeId int
    ) returns int as
    begin;
    declare @max int;
    select @max = MaxCount from TypeConstraints where TypeId = @TypeId;
      declare @count int = 
      (
        select count(*) from Data where TypeId = @TypeId
      )

      return @max - @count;
    end;
    go

    alter table Data  WITH NOCHECK add constraint test check (dbo.UdfCheckCount(TypeId) >= 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write a trigger on your database that checks this and throws an error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Table 
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    -- Do your check here to see if the type count has been exceeded
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Table WHERE TypeID = <etc ...> )
    BEGIN 
        RAISERROR ('Maximum number of rows for this type has been exceeded', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END
END
```

Then, just handle the error in your application and proceed from there.

However, I'm not sure how triggers work from an EF Code-First perspective.  I can't imagine it would cause any issues though.